# On right click, display color palette, then change color and write value to input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am quite new to the world of jQuery and am struggling to solve this.

What I want to do is have a right click menu that displays a simple color palette. Then when a color is selected, the background color of the div changes and stores the style information (e.g. `color:red`) inside of an input box called 'property'+*i* where *i* is the corresponding numeric value of the div whose color has been changed. How would I achieve this?

I am dynamically creating draggable div's with a button click each has a unique id lets say D1, D2, D3 etc. and am storing the x,y positions inside of two other input boxes - this is done with the following code...

```
var i = 1;
$("#AddDesk").click(function() {
  $("<div />", { "class":"desk", id:"D"+i }).draggable({ 
        grid: [10, 10],
        snap: ".drop-target",
        drag: function(){
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;
                console.log(xPos);
                $('#posX'+$(this).attr("id").replace('D','')).val('x:' + xPos);
                $('#posY'+$(this).attr("id").replace('D','')).val('y:' + yPos);
        }
    })
     .append("<center>D"+i+"</center>")
     .appendTo("#dContainer");
    $("<div />", { "class":"deskdata", id:"data"+i })
        .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"name"+i, "class": "data", value: "D"+i }))
        .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posX"+i, "class": "data" }))
        .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posY"+i, "class": "data" }))
        .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"property"+i, "class": "data" }))
        .appendTo("#dataContainer");
  i++;
});
```

Here is the right click menu code as it stands...

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $("<div class='custom-menu'><b>Background Color:</b><br /><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:blue\">Blue</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:aqua\">Aqua</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:aquamarine\">Aquamarine</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:green\">Green</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:darkgreen\">Dark Green</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:orange\">Orange</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:yellow\">Yellow</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:red\">Red</div></div>")
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({top: event.pageY + "px", left: event.pageX + "px"});
}).bind("click", function(event) {
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaisummers/TeM48/)** without the dynamic creation stuff.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @Malk - The question is in the second paragraph, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things. It's nearly there.

You don't need to redraw/bind a menu on each click. You can just draw it once and reuse it.

You should use `on()` instead of `bind()` for delegation goodness (like for showing the menu only for right clicking the dynamic `.group` div).

Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/QLyt2/

```
var colors = [
    "Blue",
    "Aqua",
    "Aquamarine",
    "Green",
    "DarkGreen",
    "Orange",
    "Yellow",
    "Red"
];

var $menu = [];

function buildMenu(){
    var html = [
        "<div class='custom-menu'>",
        "<b>Background Color:</b><br />"
    ];
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
        html.push("<div style=\"width:100%;background-color:" + colors[i] + ";\" class=\"color\">" + colors[i] + "</div>");
    }
    $menu = $(html.join(''))
    .appendTo("body")
    .on("click", ".color", handleClick);   
}

function handleClick(e){
    var targetId = $menu.data("target");
    $("#" + targetId).css({
        "background-color": $(this).css("background-color")
    });
    $("input[name=property"+targetId.replace(/\D/g, '')+"]").val($(this).css('background-color'));
    $menu.hide();   
}

$("#container").on("contextmenu", ".group", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($menu.length == 0){
        buildMenu();
    }
    $menu
        .show()
        .data("target", this.id)
        .css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
        });
});
$(document).on("click", function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".custom-menu").length == 0)
        $menu.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7CTbE/). I have done it very weirdly may be. I'll list you the things I have done there.

and the code is like below,

```
var idto = "";
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("<div class='custom-menu'><b>Background Color:</b><br /><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:blue\" data-color='blue' >Blue</div><div data-color='aqua' style=\"width:100%;background-color:aqua\"  data-propid='2'>Aqua</div><div data-color='aquamarine' style=\"width:100%;background-color:aquamarine\">Aquamarine</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:green\">Green</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:darkgreen\">Dark Green</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:orange\">Orange</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:yellow\">Yellow</div><div style=\"width:100%;background-color:red\">Red</div></div>")
        .appendTo("body")
        .css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
    idto = event.target.id
}).bind("click", function (event) {    
    $("div.custom-menu").hide();
});

$("body").on('click', ".custom-menu div", function() {
    $("#"+idto+"").css("background", $(this).attr('data-color'));  
    $("input[name=property"+(idto.charAt(1))+"]").val($(this).attr('data-color'));
})
```

the var idto will actually hold the id of the div on which right click was happenned. The line which does is this `idto = event.target.id`

Then I have added a click function on `.custom-menu div` to get the clicked div's color. I have added a `data-color`  attribute so as to get the color of that div. I have added it for three.

Now the problem actually with this approach is with this line

```
$("input[name=property"+(idto.charAt(1))+"]").val($(this).attr('data-color'));
```

You can even skip the data-color attribute and get the background color of that div. That would be the best way of getting the background color.

I have used `charAt`  to knoe about the index to which input I have to set the value. If you have more than two digits then this solution won't work. So there I say all the best.

Comment: You are awesome! I can use this to work from. I changed the idto.charAt(1) to idto.replace(/\D/g,'') so using regex it removes all the non number values from the string, this way it will work with more than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

change this

$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(event) {

to

$(document).on( bind, "contextmenu", function(event){

Comment: Just tried this on the fiddle and it breaks the right click menu, this also doesn't show how to update the div underneath or how to write that value to a textbox with a different id.